# contact sensor has no member named contacts

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was following [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor) tutorial , but as i try to build the code i get theis error msg:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:266:5: note:   ‘boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::bind’
 int bind(socket_type s, const socket_addr_type* addr,
     ^
/home/rob/Documents/gazebo_contact_tutorial/ContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::ContactPlugin::OnUpdate()’:
/home/rob/Documents/gazebo_contact_tutorial/ContactPlugin.cc:43:34: error: ‘class gazebo::sensors::ContactSensor’ has no member named ‘Contacts’
   contacts = this->parentSensor->Contacts();
```

How can i remove this error?
I am using ros indigo with gazebo 2.2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14278/contact-sensor-has-no-member-named-contacts/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For Gazebo 7+, it should be `Contacts()` with upper case, instead of lower case.

```
contacts = this->parentSensor->Contacts();
```

For previous versions:

```
contacts = this->parentSensor->GetContacts();
```

Be sure to check the Gazebo version on the tutorial's top-right corner.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2016-08-29**:
yes i have trieed that. First it was like that, but i changed in to lower case, but no use.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-08-29**:
But with the correct function you're probably getting a different error message, right?

**Comment by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on 2016-08-29**:
no same error: .. has no member named Contacts, i looks at the class ContactSensor reference, i can see that this class has member function called Contacts, but when i try to access it it shows error.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-08-29**:
ahh ok, now I see you're using Gazebo 2.2. You should choose the correct Gazebo version on the top right, the function used to be `GetContacts()`